# How to make a function that return an index with a limit

Tags: javascript

I've wondered how can I optimize the conditions to function that is flexible enough to return an index that has a limitation of 3 index

```
if(val === 0) return 0;
if (val === -90) return 3;
if (val === -180) return 2;
if (val === -270) return 1;
if (val === -360) return 0;
if (val === -450) return 3;

if(val === 0) return 0;
if (val === 90) return 1;
if (val === 180) return 2;
if (val === 270) return 3;
if (val === 360) return 0;
if (val === 450) return 1;
```

and so on

I wonder how to make a function that if a user increments by 90 the returns should get incremented with a limit of 3 then after 3 it will return 0 index

Comment: Is there something not optimal with the code you've written? Perhaps you could add an input example, and your expected output so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: If a user keeps increment by 90 from 360 to infinite it will have a lot of conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function f(x) {
 let z = x / 90;
 let y = z % 4;
 return y < 0 ? 4 + y : y;   
}



for(let i =  -90 * 10; i <= 90 * 10; i = i + 90) {
 console.log(`x = ${i} => result => ${f(i)}`);
}
```

```js
function f(x) {
  return ((x / 90) % 4 + 4) % 4;
}


 for(let i =  -90 * 10; i <= 90 * 10; i = i + 90) {
  console.log(`x = ${i} => result => ${f(i)}`);
 }
```

Comment: This gives `-0` for `-360` which isn't quite right.

Comment: Your second effort is correct though and looks pretty optimal.

Answer (score 0):

you should get the minimum input first, then add 360 to it.

```
val = 360+val;

if(val % 360 === 90){
    return 1
}
if(val % 360 === 180){
    return 2
}
if(val % 360 === 270){
    return 3
}
if(val % 360 === 0){
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try dividing by 90 for the positive numbers and for the negative numbers add 360 first then divide by 90.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `(val % 360) / 90`

```js
if (val % 90 !== 0) return null.

return (val % 360) / 90;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
const f = v => (v = v / 90 % 4, v < 0 ? 4 + v : v | 0);

for (let i = -450; i <= 450; i += 90) {
 console.log(`f(${i}) = ${f(i)}`);
}
```